# Customize category page for different custom taxonomies

Tags: categories, taxonomy, archives

What I'm working on are the pages that you go to after clicking on a custom taxonomy on the front-end. I'm to the point where I've duplicated category.php, renamed it taxonomy-tr_property_region.php so that I can edit how posts with the taxonomy tr_property_region are displayed.

If I understand correctly I need to edit loop.php, but I don't want taxonomy-tr_property_region.php to look the same as taxonomy-language.php is there a way to not use get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );

Example being I want to change this

```
get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );
```

To be something more like this,

```
<div>
<?php 
  $loop = whatever replaces get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' ); 
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="fullWidthContent">
<div class="trPropSearchHeader">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  <?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propCity', true); echo $meta; ?>
</div>
<div class="trPropSearchThumbnail">
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
    </a>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="trPropSearchDetailsContainer">          
  <?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propBedrooms', true); echo $meta; ?>
  <?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propBathrooms', true); echo $meta; ?>
  <?php $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rw_propDesc', true); echo $meta; ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i would do it:
why not just include another loop.php in its place, for example copy `loop.category.php`, rename it to something like `loop-copy.php` make your changes to it and call it to the template as `<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'copy' ); ?>`.